# Greasmonkey change <span> color

Tags: javascript, colors, greasemonkey, html

I want to manipulate a single color from a forum's userlist.
The User is displayed like this:

```
<span style="color:#1381A5">username</span>
```

My latest shot is this one:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(spans[i].style.color == "#1381A5") {
        var span = spans[i];
        span.style.color ='red';
    }
}
```

Do you have some hints how to pic&replace the color value ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the problem? have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your script not working is, I believe, in that line of code:

```
if(spans[i].style.color == "#1381A5") {
```

See, the `spans[i].style.color` value is:

```
rgb(19, 129, 165)
```

which is certainly not equal to `#1381A5`

One option would be to change the line above to:

```
if(spans[i].style.color === "rgb(19, 129, 165)") {
```

which should solve your issue.